# Limiting fields returned by mongo dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I use Meteor to query a mongo collection. It has for example the following entry:

```
{
    "_id": "uCfwxKXyZygcWQeiS",
    "gameType": "foobar",
    "state": "starting",
    "hidden": {
        "correctAnswer": "secret",
        "someOtherStuff": "foobar"
    },
    "personal": {
        "Y73uBhuDq2Bhk4d8W": {
            "givenAnswer": "another secret",
        },
        "hQphob8s92gbEMXbY": {
            "givenAnswer": "i have no clue"
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do now is:

- don't return the values behind "hidden"
- from the "personal" embedded document only return the values for the asking user

In code it would look something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('game', function() {
    this.related(function(user) {
        var fields = {};
        fields.hidden = 0;
        fields.personal = 0;
        fields['personal.' + this.userId] = 1;

        return Games.find({}, {fields: fields});

    }, Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {'profile.gameId': 1}}));
}
```

Obviously this won't work, because MongoDB won't allow mixed includes and excludes. On the other hand, I cannot switch to "specify only the included fields", because they can vary from gameType to gameType and it would become a large list.

I really hope that you can help me out of this. What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical example of where to use the directly controlled publication features (the `this.added/removed/changed` methods).
See the second example block a bit down the page at http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish.

With this pattern you get complete control of when and what to publish.